# __consumer_offset is unable to sync

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am using mm2 with below properties
source(A),sink(B) clusters both have their own separate zookeeper
I consume some data from topic test in source A.
then I stopped consumer, and start mirror process
when I pointed consumer with same group id to sink then it start consuming from beginning. I am expecting it should start in sink from where it left off in source.
###############

````
A.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9092
B.bootstrap.servers = localhost:9093
A->B.enabled = true
A->B.topics = test
#B->A.enabled = true
#B->A.topics = .*
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=1
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=1
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.replication.factor=1```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Kafka 2.7, MirrorMaker can automatically mirror consumer group offsets by setting `sync.group.offsets.enabled=true`.

In your example:

```
A->B.sync.group.offsets.enabled=true
```

Before 2.7, MirrorMaker does not automatically commit consumer group offsets and you need to use [`RemoteClusterUtils`](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/mirror/RemoteClusterUtils.html) to do the offsets translation.